# How to open an image in another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to make an iOS application with 2 views. First view contain two buttons: Camera and  Library. When i select Library i access the camera roll. I wanna select a photo and open it in another view. Until now i write this functions

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}   


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: Nil];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

witch open my image in the same view. How could I open this image in another view?

Comment: what do you mean by another view, are you trying to open it in another UIViewController? please elaborate more in your question or else no one could help You!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        YourSeconViewController *svc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourSeconViewController" bundle:nil];
        svc.imageView.Image = image;
        [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps I suggest are:

1. Make sure that you declared a view controller subclass, preferably with a xib file and make sure that it has an image view inside it;
2. If you aren't using any navigation controller, create one and make it be the root view controller of the window;
3. Push a view controller and set it's image view's image with the image that you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the image in another view in the same view controller is trivially simple - assuming you have a reference to the new view in your viewController, just use that:

```
 NewImageView.image = ...
```

I assume that you rather mean you want to pass the image to another view *controller*.

To do this you should initiate the transition to the new viewController from your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method.

In your new view controller you should declare a public  property that you can set:

```
@property (monatomic, strong) UIImage* Image;
```

You can set that property on the new view controller before you transition to it, and in the new view controller's viewWillAppear use that property to set the content of an imageView.

How you make the transition depends on the design of your app. For example you could use a Segue, in which case you can initiate the segue in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` and set the new view controller's property in `prepareForSegue`. Or you could create the new VC directly:

```
  MyCustomViewController* viewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];

   //pass the image ref to the new view controller here
  ViewController.image = image;

   //modally present, no navController
  [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];

   //alternatively, push via a nav controller
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```